# show $dim Ker(f+g) \leq dim (Ker f \cap Ker g) + dim (Im f \cap Im g)$ where $f,g \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$

Tags: vector-spaces

How to show $dim Ker(f+g) \leq dim (Ker f \cap Ker g) + dim (Im f \cap Im g)$ where $f,g \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ and $E, F$ are two finite dimensional vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the restriction $u:\ker(f+g)\to F,x\mapsto f(x)$.

It's not difficult to check that :

$$\ker(u)=\ker(f)\cap\ker(g)$$

and

$$\mathrm{im}(u)\subset\mathrm{im}(f)\cap\mathrm{im}(g)$$

Hence :

$$\dim(\ker(f+g))=\dim(\ker(u))+\mathrm{rank}(u)\le\dim(\ker(f)\cap\ker(g))+\dim(\mathrm{im}(f)\cap\mathrm{im}(g))$$